# Correct bounds when finding PDF of $X + Y$, where $X,Y$ i.i.d.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

> Let $X,Y \sim \mathcal{U}([0,a])$ be independent identically continuously uniform distributed real random variables.
>   Find the PDF of $Z := X + Y$.

I know that this can be accomplished via convolution:
For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X}(x - y) f_{Y}(y) \ \text{dy}
& = \frac{1}{(a - 0)^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{[0,a]}(x - y) \cdot 1_{[0,a]}(y) \ \text{dy} \\
& = \frac{1}{a^2} \int_{0}^{a} 1 \ \text{dy} \cdot 1_{[0,2a]}(x)
= \frac{1_{[0,2a]}(x)}{a}.
\end{align*}
I obtained the bounds like this.
From the second integral in the first line we have
$$
0 \le x - y \le a
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
0 \le y \le a.
$$
Adding both inequalities yields $y \le x + y \le 2a + y$ or
$$
0 \le x \le 2 a.
$$
Therefore $x < a$ and the bounded on the dy-integral are [0, a] and furthermore we know that $x \in [0,2a]$.

**Is this (result and procedure) correct and / or is there an easier way to do this?**

> In this task I faced a similar challenge:
>   Let $X,Y \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda > 0$ be independent and identically distributed.
>   Find the density of $X + Y$.

\begin{align*}
(f_{X} \ast f_{Y})(x)
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X}(x - y) f_{Y}(y) \ \text{dy} \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda e^{-\lambda (x - y)} 1_{[0, \infty)}(x - y) \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda y} 1_{[0, \infty)}(y) \ \text{dy} \\
& = \lambda^2 \int_{0}^{x} e^{-\lambda (x - y)} \cdot e^{-\lambda y} \ \text{dy} \cdot 1_{[0, \infty)}(x)
= \lambda^2 \int_{0}^{x} e^{-\lambda x} \ \text{dy} \cdot 1_{[0, \infty)}(x) \\
& = \lambda^2 x \cdot e^{-\lambda x} \cdot 1_{[0, \infty)}(x).
\end{align*}

Here the same question as above applies.

Answer (score 1):

**First part (uniform).** If you want to use the CDF method to find $P(Z \le z)$ by integration,
the following plots (made from a simulation), may help you find the
limits on integrals. I used $a = 2.$

The left-hand plot shows the region of integration
for $P(Z \le 1.5).$ For values of $z$ above $2$ it seems easiest
to break the integral into two parts. [However, because the joint distribution is uniform, this can be a high school geometry/algebra problem, if you like.]

The middle plot shows the empirical CDF (jump of $1/10^5$ at each
of $10^5$ simulated values of $Z),$ which suggests the form of
the CDF you'll get.

The right-hand plot shows a histogram of $10^5$ simulated values of
$Z.$ [A discrete analogue of this is the 'triangular' PDF from the sum upon rolling two fair dice.]

[image]

**Second part (exponential).** If you know about moment generating
functions, that's probably the easiest way to show that the sum of
two independent exponential random variables, each with rate $\lambda$
is $\mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=2,\text{rate}=\lambda).$ However, the PDF and convolution methods also work. [Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)
on gamma distributions to check your answer.]

Another simulation to indicate the result:

```
set.seed(708);  m = 10^6
x = rexp(m, .1); y = rexp(m, .1);  z = x+y
hist(z, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dgamma(x, 2, .1), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

*Notes:* (a) This exponential relationship is much used in applications, including queueing theory. [Q. A person is next in line for a bank teller whose service times are exponential with rate one every five minutes, what is the probability that person finishes being served within 8 minutes? A. In R, code `pgamma(8, 2, 1/5)` returns 0.4750691.]

(b) If the two exponential random variables have different
rates, the problem is very much messier. (If interested, perhaps google
'sum of exponentials different rates'.)

(c) In case you want it, the R code for making the figure is provided
below:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
set.seed(2019)
 m = 30000
 x = runif(m, 0, 2);  y = runif(m, 0, 2)
 plot(x, y, pch=".")
  event = (x + y < 1.5)
   points(x[event], y[event], pch=".", col="green2")
m = 10^5
 X = runif(m, 0, 2);  Y = runif(m, 0, 2)
 Z = X+Y
 plot(ecdf(Z))
 hist(X+Y, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Well, from the middle plot for the uniform I get that the CDF is non-linear, but when I integrate my PDF I get that $\mathbb{P}(Z \le x) = \frac{x}{a}$ for $0 \le x \le 2a$, which 1) is linear and 2) returns 2 for $x = 2a$, which isn't possible. Where is my mistake? Also, my CDF and PDF for $Z$ then coincide with the CDF / PDF of $X$ (or $Y$) they are just on an interval twice the size, which seems wrong, since they have to sum up ( integrate) to 1 and not 2.

Comment: As a note, unfortunately we haven't covered moment-generating functions, just characteristic functions.

Comment: Characteristic functions will do the same job. ChFs require at least a minimal knowledge of complex numbers and exist for all dist'ns. MGFs are a bit simpler to use, but do not exist for all dist'ns.

Comment: Can you show me how? Also I'd like to know if my results are correct.

Comment: Product of MGFs is MGF of sum. MGF of $EXP(rate=\lambda)$ is $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}$ for $t > \lambda).$ MGF of $GAMMA(2, \lambda)$ is  $(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t})^2.$ See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples).